# Bluebird - how to propagate errors in nested promise

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

```
PromiseA().then(function(){
    PromiseB().catch(function (e) {
        throw e;
    })
}).catch(function (e) {
    // I want exceptions thrown in the nested promise chain to end up here.
})
```

How do I get exceptions from nested promises to bubble up to the parent promise?

Comment: As always, you have to `return` promises from all your asynchronous functions, including `then` callback functions. Otherwise they cannot be awaited, and won't forward rejections either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `return` keyword,

your code can be simplified as:

```
PromiseA().then(function(){
    return PromiseB();
}).catch(function (e) {
    // I want exceptions thrown in the nested promise chain to end up here.
})
```

**Edit:**

Not sure if this is the right way, but if promise cancellation is involved and you want only to bubble up the error flow, you can wrap your promise in custom Promise which never resolves but throws error( if it happens):

```
PromiseA().then(function(){
    var myPromise = PromiseB().then...;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      myPromise.catch(reject)
    })
}).catch(function (e) {
    // I want exceptions thrown in the nested promise chain to end up here.
})
```

Comment: In this example yes, but I want a solution where that is not done

Comment: @Jonah the only way to bubble up exception is to return the promise, also promise chaining is more advisable compared to nesting, after all, promises are an alternative to the callback hell...

Comment: I agree, nesting should be avoided.  However, I found some cases where nesting is necessary. It could be wrong though.  Would you say that nesting should never ever be necessary?

Comment: @Jonah at least one scenario where nesting is necessary would be conditional calling of promise methods, but even there, you can bubble error, by returning that promise.

Comment: @Jonah: What do you mean by "*where that is not done*"? This *is* the solution.

Comment: In my case, the nested promise cannot be returned, because in some cases the promise is cancelled. If it was returned, the cancellation would cancel the entire chain including the parent, but I only want the nested promise cancelled.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, avoid using nested promises. Also always use `return` statement to return promise result from nested function. In your example, `PromiseB` result is never used and main promise chain will be resolved before `PromiseB` is resolved.

In you current situation, you could use `Promise.reject` function to bubble up error to the parent promise:

```
PromiseA()
    .then(function() {
        return PromiseB()
            .catch(function (err) {
                // TODO: error processing
                return Promise.reject(err);
            });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        // Here you'll get the same err object as in first catch
    });
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with nested promises in general. They can be very useful with closures or for dedicated error handling.

Comment: @Bergi I agree, sometimes it's useful, but I often see code with 3 or more levels of nested promises, and it looks ugly. Anyway instead of nested promises much better to use local functions with these promises.

Comment: In my case, the nested promise cannot be returned, because in some cases the promise is cancelled.  If it was returned, the cancellation would cancel the entire chain including the parent, but I only want the nested promise cancelled. However, I didn't specify that in the original question so I may just accept this one and ask a new question